# Create output file in matlab containing numeric and string cells

Tags: r, matlab, csv, output

I am currently working on a project where I have to program the same tool both in Matlab and R and compare both software options.
I started in R and now I am translating the code to Matlab but I am now stuck at the most important part. The output file that the tool creates after doing the analysis.
Basically, my tool makes an analysis that loops `n` times, and after each loop I get many variables that go into an output table. So, to be more clear, after each loop I get variables:

```
A = 123

B = 456

C = 'string1'

D = 'string2'

E = 789
```

The values in each variable change after each loop, I just want to make clear that the variables are both numeric and string values since this is what causes my problem.

In `R` what I do after each loop is:

```
outp <- cbind(A,B,C,D,E)
```

and create a data frame containing each variable in one cell arranged horizontally to afterwards add the result of each loop vertically in a new data frame:

```
outp2 <- rbind(outp2,outp)
```

so in the end I get a data frame (`outp2`) with A,B,C,D,E columns and `n` rows containing the values of each variable after each loop. So at the end of the looping process I can use `write.csv` function and create an output file of `outp2` that contains both numeric and string columns.

I tried to do this in Matlab but I cannot find a function that can join the data in the same way I am doing it in R because using brackets `'[]'` only allows me to join numeric kind of variables. So basically my question is: How can I replicate what I am doing in R in Matlab?

I hope I was clear enough, I found it a bit hard to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append your output with a cell array, first using curly brackets to declare your cell format (empty `{}` or containing your data `{...}`), then using brackets `[...]` to concatenate the output (one line after the others using `;`).

```
out_array = {};        %initialize empty

%vertical concatenation with ";"
for ii = 1:3
    out_array = [out_array; {123, 456, 'string1', 'string2', 789}];
end
```

This gives

> out_array =
>
> ```
> [123]    [456]    'string1'    'string2'    [789]
> [123]    [456]    'string1'    'string2'    [789]
> [123]    [456]    'string1'    'string2'    [789]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Don't now if this solves your problem, but in Matlab you can do things like

```
oupt = {123, 456, 'string1', 'string2', 789}
```

Just use curly braces instead of square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

As they have said before, use curly braces to create a cell array. I imagine A, B, C, D, and E are your table headers and you already have the data that goes under them, so I'd do it like this:

```
outp = { A , B , C , D , E };
# This next step is only to have some data...
outp2 = magic(5);
outp2 = num2cell(outp2);
output = [ outp ; outp2 ]

output = 

    [123]    [456]    'string1'    'string2'    [789]
    [ 17]    [ 24]    [      1]    [      8]    [ 15]
    [ 23]    [  5]    [      7]    [     14]    [ 16]
    [  4]    [  6]    [     13]    [     20]    [ 22]
    [ 10]    [ 12]    [     19]    [     21]    [  3]
    [ 11]    [ 18]    [     25]    [      2]    [  9]
```